# Array inside a 3 column tabular

Tags: tables

I am having a tabular with 3 columns. Inside each column, I am trying to use an array. But, all the array's are coming in 1st column.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
          a4paper,
          total={170 mm,257 mm},
          left=20 mm,
          top=20 mm,
          }
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\newcommand{\wt}[2]{\underset{\substack{\textstyle\uparrow\\\hidewidth\mathstrut#2\hidewidth}}{#1}}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Solution :} \\[0.5 cm]
    \hspace*{0.5 cm}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0.2em}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
    \begin{tabular}{c | c | c}
        (a) 9's complement :\\[0.25 cm]
        $\begin{array}{ccccc}
              & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
            - & 5 & 8 & 4 & 2 \\
            \cline{2-5}
              & 4 & 1 & 5 & 7 
        \end{array}$ &
        (b) 7's complement :\\[0.25 cm]
        $\begin{array}{ccccc}
              & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
            - & 6 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
            \cline{2-5}
              & 1 & 3 & 5 & 4 
        \end{array}$ &
        (c) 15's complement :\\[0.25 cm]
        $\begin{array}{ccccc}
              & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} \\
            - & \mathrm{A} & 9 & 6 & \mathrm{D} \\
            \cline{2-5}
              & 5 & 6 & 9 & 2 
        \end{array}$
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output obtained:

The output obtained for the above code is:

[image: Obtained Output]

Desired Output:

The output desired is:

[image: Desired Output]

Can anyone help me to solve this? Please provide a standard solution, which would work for different array dimensions as well.

Comment: You can't use `\\ ` inside of a `c` type column in order to obtain a linebreak inside of this specific cell. Using `\\ ` here always starts a new row in your table.

Comment: Using something like `\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}(a) 9's complement : & (b) 7's complement : & (c) 15's complement : \\ $\begin{array}{ccccc}& 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 \\- & 5 & 8 & 4 & 2 \\ \cline{2-5}& 4 & 1 & 5 & 7 \end{array}$ & $\begin{array}{ccccc} & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\ - & 6 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\\cline{2-5}& 1 & 3 & 5 & 4
\end{array}$ & $\begin{array}{ccccc} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} \\ - & \mathrm{A} & 9 & 6 & \mathrm{D} \\\cline{2-5}& 5 & 6 & 9 & 2  \end{array}$\end{tabular}` should result in the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array should be in the 2nd row of the tabular. However, I suggest using the `tasks` package and its eponymous environment for a more natural syntax.

*Unrelated*: I removed packages already loaded by other packages (e.g. amsfonts is loaded by amssymb, amsmath is loaded by mathtools). Note that utf8 is now supposed to be the input encoding by default. Using the `matrix` environment in the place of array simplifies a bit the code. Also, the rules from `booktabs` have some vertical padding. I used them in the code with tasks.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
          a4paper,
          total={170 mm,257 mm},
          left=20 mm,
          top=20 mm,
          }
\usepackage{bm, amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tasks, booktabs}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\newcommand{\wt}[2]{\underset{\substack{\textstyle\uparrow\\\hidewidth\mathstrut#2\hidewidth}}{#1}}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Solution :} \\[0.5 cm]
    \hspace*{0.5 cm}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0.2em}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
{\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c | c | c@{}}
        (a) 9's complement : &
        (b) 7's complement : &
        (c) 15's complement :\\[0.25 cm]
        $\begin{matrix}
              & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
            - & 5 & 8 & 4 & 2 \\
            \cline{2-5}
              & 4 & 1 & 5 & 7
        \end{matrix}$ &
        $\begin{matrix}
              & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
            - & 6 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
            \cline{2-5}
              & 1 & 3 & 5 & 4
        \end{matrix}$ &
        $\begin{matrix}
              & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} \\
            - & \mathrm{A} & 9 & 6 & \mathrm{D} \\
            \cline{2-5}
              & 5 & 6 & 9 & 2
        \end{matrix}$
    \end{tabular}
}%
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*),label-width=1.3em] (3)
  \task 9's complement :

        $\begin{matrix}
              & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
            - & 5 & 8 & 4 & 2 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
              & 4 & 1 & 5 & 7
        \end{matrix}$
%%
\task 7's complement :

$\begin{matrix}
              & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 \\
            - & 6 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
              & 1 & 3 & 5 & 4
        \end{matrix}$
%%
\task 15's complement :

        $\begin{matrix}
              & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{F} \\
            - & \mathrm{A} & 9 & 6 & \mathrm{D} \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
              & 5 & 6 & 9 & 2
        \end{matrix}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping....